# Solve recursive function $T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/6) + n^{\sqrt{\log{n}}}$

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, recursion, order-theory

In one of my college assignments, I came up with the following recursive function which I'm asked to solve:

$T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/6) + n^{\sqrt{\log{n}}}$

I tried a change of the variable or the recursion tree but I couldn't figure out its solution. I'll be highly grateful if I get some hint about how I can go about this.

Comment: This can likely be solved using the [Akra–Bazzi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), a generalization of the master theorem.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus as $g(n) \not \in O(n^c)$, we can't use the Akra-Bazzi. Right?

Comment: According to Wikipedia you're right.

Comment: Try proving by induction that $T(n) = O(n^{\sqrt{\log n}})$. If you succeed, then $T(n) = \Theta(n^{\sqrt{\log n}})$.